# Error en sintaxis

Tags: javascript

Alguien me puede decir donde esta el error de sintaxis aqui?, estuve horas intentando arreglar llaves y usando validadores de sintaxs, pero nada, adjunto el codigo por si alguien me puede ayudar:

[codigo](https://hastebin.com/sudemopawa.js)

Si alguien me podria ayudar porfavor, me vendria muy bien una mano.
Error:

```
0|server  | /home/ubuntu/MinewoolBot/server.js:1362
0|server  | });
0|server  |  ^
0|server  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
0|server  |     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
0|server  |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
0|server  |     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
0|server  |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
0|server  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
0|server  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerForkLegacy.js:28:21)
0|server  |     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
0|server  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
```

PD: La linea no tiene importancia, por que en cuanto arreglo como me dice el error me da otro error, es un bucle.

Comment: Va a ayudar mucho hagas lo siguiente: agregues el mensaje de error que obtienes y que agregues aquí el código, checa [ask]

Comment: El codigo es muy largo y stackoverflow me dice que debo poner mas detalles, lo cual no se me ocurren mas, y ahora mismo pongo el error

Comment: Agrega el codigo a la pregunta. solo la parte relevante del mismo. Seguro hay mucho ahi que no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: En la línea 51 está demás el }); en la imagen que adjuntaste.

Comment: Revisé su código y solo son llaves y paréntesis sin cerrar correctamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He formateado el código y añadido los parentesis y corchetes que faltaban.

He actualizado indicando lo que fallaba en tu código.

Creo que el problema esta que no tienes claros los callbacks.

Un callback es una función(suele ser anónima) que pasas a otra función para que se ejecute cuando haya finalizado la operación. Normalmente son para ejecutar código asíncrono.

Y parece que no cierras las funciones que reciben como parámetro un callback(otra función)

Por ejemplo:

```js
const db = {
  all: (callback) => {
    // hacer una operación como query, insert, update que suele ser costosa
    // pues tu pasas el callback para que te informe cuando haya acabado
    setTimeout(() => callback(), 1000); // imagina que es una query y tarda 1s pues luego de 1s llamara a mi funcion que le he pasado como argumento 
  
  }
}

db.all(() => {
  alert('callback')
}); //<-- a ti te faltaban por cerra las funciones que recibian callback
```

```
if (message.channel.id == "632585423318679572") {
    if (message.author.bot) {

    } else {
        var db = new sqlite3.Database('sqlite.db', (err) => {
            db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS verificaciones (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id2 INTEGER, nick_minecraft TEXT, id_user TEXT, nick_discord TEXT, status TEXT)');
            db.all(`SELECT * FROM verificaciones WHERE id_user = ${message.author.id}`, (err, filas) => {
                if (Object.keys(filas) >= 1) {
                    message.delete();
                    message.author.send("No te puedes verificar 2 veces");
                } else {
                    var random_id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 565939232782321301234) + 1);
                    db.run(`INSERT INTO verificaciones (id, id2,nick_minecraft, id_user, nick_discord, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [null, random_id, message.content, `${message.author.id}`, message.author.tag, 'Pendiente']).then(() => {
                        db.all(`SELECT * FROM verificaciones WHERE id_user = ${message.author.id}`, (err, filas) => {
                            var aprobarChannel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.id === "694652755788431370");
                            var avisoVerificacion = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                                .setTitle("Nueva verificacion!")
                                .setDescription("Usa mw!acceptverify (id) o mw!accv (id) para aprobar una verificacion. \n Para rechazar una verificacion puedes usar mw!rejectverify (id) o mw!rjv (id).")
                                .addField("ID", random_id)
                                .addField("Nick minecraft", message.content)
                                .addField("Nick discord", message.author.tag);
                            aprobarChannel.send(avisoVerificacion).then((message2) => {
                                message2.react('✅');
                                message2.react('❌');
                                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                                    return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && message.guild.member(user).roles.find(r => r.id === "562600078380892166") || message.guild.member(user).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR") && !user.bot;
                                };

                                message2.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 8.64e+8, errors: ['time'] })
                                    .then(collected => {
                                        const reaction = collected.first();

                                        if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
                                            message.member.removeRole(message.guild.roles.find(r => r.id === "632584543722930176"));
                                            aprobarChannel.send("Verificacion aprobada!");
                                            message.author.send("**Tu verificacion fue aprobada, ya tienes acceso al discord de minewool completo!**");
                                            db.run(`DELETE FROM verificaciones WHERE nick_minecraft = "${message.content}"`);
                                        } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌') {
                                            message.member.kick("Tu verificacion fue rechazada").then(() => {
                                                aprobarChannel.send("Verificacion rechazada!");
                                            });
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .catch(collected => {
                                        message2.channel.send('Debes reaccionar con :white_check_mark: o :x:');
                                    });

                                message.author.send("Tu verificacion fue enviada con exito");
                            });
                        }); // faltaba por cerrar el parentesis del metodo de db.all
                    }); // faltaba por cerra el parentesis del then, 
                }
            }); // faltaba por cerrar el parentesis del metodo de db.all
        }); // te faltaba por cerrar el contructor de Database
    }
}
```

Comment: Le ayudaría mucho al OP (dado que ya lo externo) le indiques donde fue que estaban los errores

Comment: @BetaM hecho. he indicado los errores